# Windows Phone 8 - Exception while loading designer

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I have Windows 8 Enterprise Edition installed in my Machine. I am facing problem while designing windows phone 8 application development. The designer part throws an exception

> System.Exception Package failed updates, dependency or conflict
>   validation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CF3)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String
>   applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary
>   environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory
>   factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo,
>   FrameworkName targetFramework, String identifier, String
>   baseDirectory)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary
>   boundary)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary
>   boundary)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type
>   type)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedExportProvider.Initialize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExpressionHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateExportProvider(IIsolationTarget
>   isolationTarget, ICatalogFactory catalogFactory, IExportFilter filter)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget
>   isolationTarget)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget
>   isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry&
>   entry)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken
>   cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo
>   culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.b__6()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

As an additional information, If I am using blend for designing purpose and after some designing I use Visual Studio to open the solution the design loads properly. Looks like the problem is while creating solution using VS2012.

I am trying to figure out the root cause and solution for this problem. Please, help

Answer (score 2):

The [error code stands for the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh973484%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The package failed update, dependency, or conflict validation.
>
> > Possible causes:
> >
> > 1. The incoming package conflicts with an installed package.
> > 2. A specified package dependency can't be found.
> > 3. The package doesn't support the correct processor architecture. Check the AppXDeployment-Server event log for more info.

Can you:

- Create a Windows Store App and other XAML based applications without
  the designer having issues?
- Open a WP8 app without the designer having issues?

Does the:
PC meet the [requirements for the WP8 SDK?](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471)

> Supported Operating System Windows 8, Windows 8 Pro Operating system
>   type: Windows 8 64-bit (x64) client versions Hardware:
>   6.5 GB of free hard disk space 4 GB RAM 64-bit (x64) CPU Windows Phone 8 Emulator: Windows 8 Pro edition or greater Requires a processor that
>   supports Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)
>    -Just because the SDK can be installed doesn't mean that it meets the requirements!

- Application have dependencies?
  If yes: Are they properly references with all the needed assemblies?

Have you:

- Installed all Windows updates + Visual Studio Updates
- Tried a Visual Studio repair

Do the things above an restart
You could even try to re-install VS2012

Biggest question is, did it ever work- and if yes, what has changed since then?

Comment: Thank for replying Iris.

PC meets the requirements for the WP8 SDK. I have created few more applications it worked fine. Designer loads fine. I don't know what has happened all of a sudden it stopped loading the designer part and throws that exception.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. The solution is to get the developer license and viola there should be no error.