# Design view of Windows phone application is not rendered

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am developing windows phone application. I got an error about rendering design view of MainPage.xaml. The given exception is

> Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation.
>
> Windows cannot install package
>   App.aa7050f22.a32c7.a4b8d.aaaef.a034e3abccbf2 because this package
>   depends on another package that could not be found. This package
>   requires minimum version 0.0.0.0 of framework
>   Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.Debug published by any publisher to install.
>   Provide the framework along with this package.    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String
>   applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary
>   environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory
>   factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo,
>   FrameworkName targetFramework, String identifier, String
>   baseDirectory)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary
>   boundary)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary
>   boundary)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type
>   type)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExpressionHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget
>   isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget
>   isolationTarget)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget
>   isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry&
>   entry)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken
>   cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo
>   culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.b__6()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Comment: What does your XAML looks like in MainPage?

Answer (score 0):

May be you will find this helpfull [Exception while loading designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506470/windows-phone-8-exception-while-loading-designer)

[Troubleshooting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh973484(v=vs.85).aspx)

Or try to remove microsoft acccout sync